# Editing 2 orders simultaneously bug

Tags: magento-1.7, edit-order, create-order

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click <kbd>Edit</kbd> on first order, i.e 000000001
2. Click <kbd>Edit</kbd> on second order, i.e 000000002
3. Click <kbd>Add Products</kbd> on first order edit screen
4. Select any product and click <kbd>Add Selected Product(s) to Order</kbd>

You'll now see that the contents of 000000001 are all of the product(s) from 000000002 - as well as the product you selected.

I've also noticed some strange behavior when it comes to placing the orders after editing them whereby for instance the editing of 000000002 will result in it's new increment id being 000000001-1.

I think this bug may stem from the `adminhtml/session_quote` object (`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Session/Quote.php`). Does this mean that Magento can only handle the editing of a single order per session? Surely it would differentiate between the session objects using the parent entity id or something along those lines?

**Edit:** The same behavior is experienced when placing two orders simultaneously, which leads me to believe it's definitely related to the inability to split the `adminhtml/session_quote` objects on a per parent order entity id basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is a bug. It's rather a limitation on how the admin edit order is implemented.
When you hit <kbd>Edit</kbd> on and order (and when you create and order from scratch) in the backend the session is involved. See how the `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_EditController` and `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController` classes look like and what they do.

So when you hit edit on the second order, the session is cleared (see `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_EditController::startAction`) and you are not editing the first order anymore.

But the form from the first edited order is filled with data from the first order. only the ajax calls you make from this point on in the edit order screen will return values from the second order you edit.
That's why you get mixed results from the first and second order.

When submiting the form from the first order, you are submitting data like customer id or currency from the first order but you got the items from the second order.

The lesson here is to never edit 2 orders within the same session.

Comment: you're right, it is a limitation. It's a pretty annoying one. Have you ever seen a work-around for this?

Comment: I totally agree, it's better to not edit 2 orders at the same time. It's the same with products, when you edit two products at the same time, we have experienced these kind of issues as well (products appearing in the wrong category, and URL issues). Better to open an incognito window (or a different browser, not a browser window), when you'd like to do multiple edits at once, so it creates a new session.

Comment: I got a complaint like this a few years ago from the gals working on the sales department for a website I've been working on. That's why I know how this works. I tried to change the way the edited orders are kept in the session, buy involving the order id of the order being edited and a random string when an order is created but ended up spending too much time on it without any conclusive results so "we" took the decision to drop it. The only workaround was to use 2 different sessions (2 different browsers) when editing 2 orders. Sorry I have nothing else on this.

Comment: No problem! Appreciate the insight. I believe we'll likely also take that approach.

Comment: @user5972 - regarding your mention of the duplicate product editing "limitation". I've tested that quite thoroughly and am not able to reproduce this in 1.7.0.2, it works perfectly fine for me when editing both categories & URLs simultaneously between products.